# Sql Syntax Error at Line 1 using VB.net and Mysql server

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am getting an Sql syntax error check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near line 1. I am trying to save to my database. I am using VB.net.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class AddStudent
Dim mydbcon As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles      Button1.Click
    mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
    mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=jared;password=jared;database=database"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        mydbcon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Insert into database.scitech (Name,Surname,Number,College,Course,Year) values ('" & TextBox1name.Text & "','" & TextBox2su.Text & "','" & TextBox3num.Text & "'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
        reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        mydbcon.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        mydbcon.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing your variables with literals it seems like you're missing a right parenthesis:

```
"Insert into database.scitech (Name,Surname,Number,College,Course,Year) values ('abc','def','ghi'"
```

Might be a good idea to output your query when debugging SQLs.